# Working with numbers

Tags: rebus

I met my old friend. When I ask him what you are working on now, here's his answer:

```
0 1 2 3 [4] 5 [6] 7 8 9
```

What is his job?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your old friend is working on

> FORENSICS, using science, perhaps numbers, to solve a crime.

We know this because of the digits 0 to 9,

> FOUR 'N SIX are highlighted! (which sounds like our answer)

What about the other numbers?

> Specifically, he's working with "digital forensics", since we are looking at a list of all digits, or 'digit all'.

Comment: almost, rot13(Gurer vf n ernfba jul V chg bgure ahzoref gurer)

Comment: rot13(Lhcf, V guvax vg'f fbyirq. Zl npghny nafjre vf "qvtvg-nyy sbhe-a-fvk")

Comment: @mailioboro rot13(Rqvgrq gung va. Abj V nz sbaqyl vzntvavat guvf fnzr chmmyr, ohg fvzcyl vapyhqr 4,6 bayl, naq eraqre gurz va qvtvgny ypq sbezng. Gung jbhyq erdhver n ovg yrff bs n yrnc va ybtvp.)

Comment: I thought that too! and somehow I choose this approach :) but thanks for the suggestion